# sql импорт из файла

Tags: mysql, база-данных, импорт

Всем добрый день!
Есть файл дампа базы данных, нужно его импортировать, но при импорте выскакивает такая бяка

```
-------------------------------------------------------
-- Host:                         localhost
-- Server version:               5.5.41 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
-- Server OS:                    Win64
-- HeidiSQL Version:             9.1.0.4913
-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- Dumping structure for table mac_system2.edit_stats
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `edit_stats`
```

Не подскажите, как это лечить и выгрузить все-таки этот файлик?

Comment: А "бяка"-то собственно где?

Comment: #1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MariaDB на предмет корректного синтаксиса около '--------------------------------------------------------
-- Host:               ' на строке 1

Comment: В самой первой строке после первых двух тире добавьте пробел. Ну или просто удалите самую первую строку.